# Get npm error npm ERR! 404 '@my-package@2.0.0' is not in this registry when try to publish new npm package version to npm

Tags: github, npm, package.json, npm-publish

I get below `npm` error when trying to publish a new version of my package to npm.

The package is 'public' and previously published by someone else.

- updated code and merged to master
- run `npm version major` and merged `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to master
- `npm login`
- `npm publish`

I get below error:

> npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/ npm ERR! code
> E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT
> https://registry.npmjs.org/@my-package - Not found npm ERR! 404  npm
> ERR! 404  '@my-package@2.0.0' is not in this registry.

Answer (score 0):

I received a 404 until I provided a repository field in `package.json` when publishing to Github Packages. Unhelpful error.

Comment: I figured out. My username isn't a member of the 'scoped' organisation. In the past somebody else created this package. in the `package.json` there is: "name": "@company-name/my-package",  I have to find a way, my npm username gets added to the organisation `@company-name`